Form Submission Issue: Error with Laravel and React
I am working on a property renting project in Laravel and I got to a point where I needed to make the room management part e.g. Adding How Many Rooms the listing has and how many beds are there in each room:
The problem is, when I try submitting it, I get the unprocessable content error and have no idea why.
It's worth noting that I handled my form submission thru ajax, but I thought it would be easier to make the room manager in react.
Here's the full react code:
// import react from "react";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import '../../css/app.css'
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import exiosInstance from '../axiosConfig'
import axiosInstance from "../axiosConfig";



interface bedType {
    id : number,
    name: string
}
const RoomManager = () => {
    const [roomCount, setRoomCount] = useState(1);
    const [bedCount, setBedCount] = useState(1);
    const [bedTypes, setBedTypes] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [rooms, setRoom] = useState([{
        bedCount:1,
        beds: [{bedType: ''}]

    }])
    useEffect(() => {
        axiosInstance.get('/bed_types').
            then(response => {
            setBedTypes(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching Bed Types", error);
        });
    }, []);
    const addRooms = () => {
        setRoomCount(prevState => prevState + 1);
        setRoom(prevRooms => [...prevRooms, {bedCount: 1, beds: [{bedType: ''}]}]) //creates a new array that includes all the existing rooms from prevState and adds a new room with an initial bed count of 1 at the end.
    }
    const removeRooms = () => {
        if(roomCount > 1){
            setRoomCount(prevState => prevState - 1);
            setRoom(prevRooms => prevRooms.slice(0,prevRooms.length-1))
        }

    }
    const addBed = (roomIndex: number) => {
        setRoom(prevRooms =>
        {
                const updated = [...prevRooms]
                updated[roomIndex].bedCount += 1;
                updated[roomIndex].beds.push({bedType: ''})
                return updated;
        });
    };

    const removeBed = (roomIndex:number) => {
        if (rooms[roomIndex].bedCount > 1) {
            setRoom(prevRooms => {
                const updatedRooms = [...prevRooms];
                updatedRooms[roomIndex].bedCount -= 1; // Decrement bed count for the specified room
                updatedRooms[roomIndex].beds.pop();
                return updatedRooms;
            });
        }
    };

    const handleBedTypeChange = (roomIndex: number, bedIndex: number, value: string) => {
        setRoom(prevRooms => {
            const updatedRooms = [...prevRooms];
            updatedRooms[roomIndex].beds[bedIndex].bedType = value;
            return updatedRooms;
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try{
            const payload = { rooms };
            console.log('Payload:', payload);
            const response = await axios.post(`/create`, {rooms})
            console.log('Response:', response.data);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
        }

    }

    return(

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="mt-5 mb-5 w-full h-auto flex flex-col items-center justify-center border relative">

            <div id="room_count" className="h-10 mt-2 mb-2 min-w-20 w-1/3 flex self-center items-center justify-center bg-white rounded-md border border-black">
                <span className="w-full text-center text-xl font-extrabold cursor-pointer select-none" id="minus" onClick={removeRooms}>-</span>
                <span id="num" className="text-xl divide-gray-500 font-bold select-none">{roomCount}</span>
                <span className="w-full text-center text-xl font-extrabold cursor-pointer select-none" id="plus" onClick={addRooms}>+</span>
            </div>

            <div id="room_manager" className="w-full flex flex-wrap">
                {rooms.map((room, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="pl-5 room min-h-20 h-auto border mt-2 relative w-full pr-5">
                        <div className="">
                            <span className="">Room {index + 1}</span>
                            <p className="text-sm font-bold my-5">How many beds does Room {index + 1} have? </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="w-full flex items-center left mb-5">
                            <div className="w-1/4 flex items-center justify-between space-x-1">
                                <span
                                    className="w-10 rounded-full bg-gray-200 flex items-center justify-center text-xl font-bold cursor-pointer select-none py-1 px-1"
                                    onClick={() => removeBed(index)}
                                >
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="2" stroke="currentColor" className="w-3 h-3">
                                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M18 12H6"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span className="text-sm font-bold select-none">{room.bedCount}</span>
                                <span
                                    className="w-10 rounded-full bg-gray-200 flex items-center justify-center text-xl font-bold cursor-pointer select-none py-1 px-1"
                                    onClick={() => addBed(index)}
                                >
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="2" stroke="currentColor" className="w-3 h-3">
                                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M12 6v12m6-6H6"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {Array.from({ length: rooms[index].bedCount }, (_, bedIndex) => (
                            <div key={bedIndex} className="min-h-20 h-auto">
                                <div className="w-full flex justify-between">
                                    <span className="">Bed {bedIndex + 1}</span>
                                    <select
                                        value={room.beds[bedIndex].bedType}
                                        onChange={(e) => handleBedTypeChange(index, bedIndex, e.target.value)}
                                    >
                                        {bedTypes.map(bedType => (
                                            <option key={bedType.id} value={bedType.id}>{bedType.name}</option>
                                        ))}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="mt-5 px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};


export default RoomManager;


And this is the controller:
public function store(Request  $request){


    try {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:listings,name',
            'capacity' => 'required|integer',
            'price_night' => 'required|numeric',
            'description' => 'required',
            'street' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'country_code' => 'required|max:2',
            'number' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'apartment' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'floor' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'state' => 'nullable|max:2',
            'zip_code' => 'nullable',
            'pictures.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'property_type_id' => 'required|integer|exists:property_types,id',
            'surface_area' => 'required|numeric',
            'rooms' => 'required|array',
            'rooms.*.bedCount' => 'required|integer|min:1',
            'rooms.*.beds' => 'required|array',
            'rooms.*.beds.*.bedType' => 'required|integer|exists:bed_types,id'

        ]);
        $address = Address::create($request->only(['street', 'city', 'country_code', 'number', 'apartment', 'floor', 'state', 'zip_code', 'property_type_id', 'surface_area']));
        $validated['address_id'] = $address->id; //hozzadom a most letrehozott address id -t
        $validated['user_id'] = session('userID');
        $listing = Listing::create($validated);
        if ($request->hasFile('pictures')) {  //checks if any files have been uploaded to the pictures array
            foreach ($request->file('pictures') as $file) {  //iterates over every file uploaded in the pictures field
                $file_name = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName(); // getClientOriginal name returns the original name of the file
                $file->move(public_path() . '/images/', $file_name); //this will "upload" the file, in our case it will be put in a  folder in the current path
                ListingPicture::create([
                    'listing_id' => $listing->id,
                    'url' => '/images/' . $file_name
                ]);

            }
        }

        $roomData = $request->input('rooms');
        foreach ($roomData as $room) {
            $bedroom = Bedroom::create([
                'listing_id' => $listing->id,
                'name' => 'Room ' . ($room['name'] ?? 'Unnamed')
            ]);

            foreach ($room['beds'] as $bed) {
                Bed::create([
                    'bedroom_id' => $bedroom->id,
                    'bed_type_id' => $bed['bedType']
                ]);
            }
        }


        return response()->json(['redirect' => route('listing.show', $listing->id)]);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        \Log::error('Validation Errors:', $e->errors());
        return response()->json(['errors' => $e->errors()], 422);
     }
}

Any help would be appreciated!
Tried logging the payload that's to be sent for the backend to process
